# Who is this girl police, likely a crossover character, in episode 4?

Tags: mezzo-dsa

For a background character, the girl police's design stands out too much, so I suspect that she is a crossover character or has at least some background to her. Or do animators occasionally just like to draw a background character so differently? But she doesn't even dress like a policewoman!

[image: "Yeah! I've always wanted to do that!"]
[image: "Yes, emergency vehicles passing by."]
[image]